# does Magento support galera cluster for Mysql?

Tags: database

I have read many blogs related to this argument but cannot find out the final answer . Is it possible to adopt galera cluster for Mysql as database solution for Magento ? Is is enough to add the missing primary keys ,move Myisam table to Innodb and remove the full text index ?

Comment: the removal of fulltext index maybe is not needed starting from Mysql 5.6 which supports fulltext index on Innodb .